# Hypersurface orthogonal congruences

Tags: general-relativity

[image: p.226 General Relativity]In his book "General Relativity" on p. 226 Wald writes that the congruence of all timelike geodesics through $p$ is hypersurface orthogonal. I dont't really understand why. Can anybody help me out here? Does this also apply to the congruence of all null geodesics through $p$?

Comment: Can you provide maybe a picture of the book page? As far as I understand, null congruences are hypersurface orthogonal, due to which $\omega _{\mu \nu }=0$, simplifying the Raychaudari equation.

Comment: But why is it then, that the Raychaudhuri equation for null geodesic congruences contains the $\omega_{\mu\nu}\omega^{\mu\nu}$ part?

Comment: Well, the Raychaudari equation is something like $-\frac{1}{2}\theta -8\pi GT_{\mu \nu }x^{\mu }x^{\nu }-\sigma _{\mu \nu }\sigma ^{\mu \nu }+\omega _{\mu \nu }\omega ^{\mu \nu }$. For orthogonal null congruences $\omega =0$. For timelike geodesics, I have detailed it in an answer below.

Answer (score 0):

From Hawking and Ellis, see the following discussion from proposition 4.5.1 and lemma 4.5.2. If $\mathcal{U}$ is a convex normal neighbourhood around some $p$, the points that can be reached from $p$ via a causal (non-spacelike) curve in $\mathcal{U}$ are those that look like $\mathrm{exp}_{p}\mathbf{X}$, for $\mathbf{X}\in T_{p}$ and $g(\mathbf{X}, \mathbf{X})\leq 0$. That is to say that the future (or past) boundary of null curves, $\partial J^{\pm }$ are formed by null curves from $p$, and the boundary of the region in $\mathcal{U}$ that can be reached via a causal curve from $p$ is composed of these null curves originating from $p$. The case for timelike geodesics is that those timelike geodesics passing through $p$ are orthogonal to the surfaces of constant $\sigma $ (constant $\tau $ in Wald's book) -- see figure 11 for a schematic view of this. Maybe there are some relations to *promptness* of geodesics. For instance, proposition 4.5.13 is the statement that, if $\gamma _{t}$ is a null geodesic that is orthogonal to some spacelike surface $\mathscr{S}$ reaching to some point $p$, then no variations to $\gamma $ will yield a timelike curve joining $p$ and $\mathscr{S}$, provided that there are no conjugate points. Not that this is relevant to answering your question, but in general the links between variations and orthogonality of geodesics to surfaces was the first thought in my mind on seieng your question.

Comment: First of all thank you, for the quick response. But i still don't really get why the congruence of null geodesics emanating from $p$ is hypersurface orthogonal.

Comment: @benny Welcome. I am not sure they _necessarily_ have to be orthogonal to some spacelike submanifold. The aspect of promptness I mentioned is precisely for this; if a null geodesic from $\mathscr{S}$ to $p$ has to be prompt, it has to be orthogonal to $\mathscr{S}$; otherwise, you could vary it so that it reaches point $p$ via another causal curve earlier. See Witten's excellent review, Light Rays, Singularities, and All That for more on promptness (and Hawking and Ellis 4.5.13). In Witten's notes, there is a dedicated section on orthogonal null geodesics. Orthogonality is only for promptness.

Comment: @benny I may be missing something else, though, so in case this mention of orthogonal null geodesics is used more strongly somewhere, I would be glad to know. I have worked with such geodesics (for violation of the covariant entropy bound), but I wasn't sure there was an explicit reason to consider null geodesics without orthogonality. If it is not clear, I will edit the answer to clarify.

Comment: I found a paper of Wald (Theorems on gravitational time delay and
related issues) where in eq. (13) he seems to be using that $\omega_{ab}$ is vanishing along the congruence of null geodesics emanating from $p$. He is referring to the paper "Proof of Classical Versions of the Bousso Entropy Bound and of the Generalized
Second Law" where he argues in B. that $\omega_{ab}$ vanishes. But i don't understand how this is connected to the congruence of null geodesics emanating from $p$. Do you perhaps understand that?

Comment: @benny Yes. Interestingly, I wrote a paper on the covariant entropy bound as well https://arxiv.org/abs/2301.02579 and gave a talk at ICTS. (The version on arXiv has to be revised, it is too naive.) The covariant entropy bound is the statement that given a codimension-2 surface $I$ with a compact boundary $\partial I$, the entropy is bounded like $S\leq n\frac{\text{Area of } \partial I}{4G_{N}\hbar }$, where $n$ are the number of light-sheets, i.e. compact orthogonal null hypersurfaces bound by a negative initial expansion, which are at most four. If you are interested, tag me on h-bar.

Comment: @benny More preferably, I would suggesting going through inspire or arXiv for papers on CEB or generalized entropy. See for instance, the papers by Engelhardt, Wall, Bousso, and others on these things. H bar is not a preferable place though, just realised. Or, I can update the answer.

Comment: Sounds interesting! Again thanks for all your help. It already helped. I think i just need to think about it some more.

Answer (score 0):

In Minkowski space, an exploding bag of clocks travelling radially at all speeds from the origin, determines a space-time hyperbolic, spatial spherical coordinate system in the future light cone  by labelling all points of equal proper time as belonging to the hyperboloid tangent to the light cone with the same proper time coordinate as the central point at rest.

By definition any radial geodesic is Lorentz orthogonal to any tangent vector to a proper time hypersurface, simply by the argument, that you can take that geodesic as the central one with velocity zero, it's neighbourhood particles of the same proper time defining the orthogonal spatial Lorentz plane there.

This simple principle is applicable to nonflat metrics, too, and generates aproximate spherical Riemann normal coordinates with spatial elliptic corrections for short proper time families of hypersurfaces.